# how to add two event handlers to a element or node in combined form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, chaining

I know that in jQuery we can add multiple event handlers in combined form but how to do it in pure Javascript?

How can we attach event handlers in combined form like this:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].onclick.onkeypress = function() {
    alert(1);
}
```

But It throws a typeError.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery lets you be more concise but this isn't really different :

```
var e = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
e.onclick = e.onkeypress = function() {
    alert(1);
};
```

And if you want to avoid polluting the global namespace with the `element`, do this :

```
(function(){
  var e = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
  e.onclick = e.onkeypress = function() {
    alert(1);
  };
})();
```

You could define a function to add chaining to `addEventListener` but is there really a point ?

Comment: @ShadowWizard In fact addEventListener wasn't even helping if the goal was to be more concise when doing what OP does. I removed it.

Comment: @dystroy your answer is good! but you missed `on` before keypress.